# i need to bring one div in the same line as the pagination controls present in ag-grid-angular

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid-angular

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-style">
  <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;" class="ag-theme-alpine profile-listing" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef" [rowData]="rowData"
    [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [treeData]="true" [animateRows]="true" [getDataPath]="getDataPath"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [headerHeight]="0" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [localeText]="localeText" [domLayout]="'autoHeight'" [rowHeight]="50" *ngIf="isRefresh"  [pagination]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="10"
    ></ag-grid-angular>

    
<div class="pagination-size">
  Page Size:
  <select (change)="onPageSizeChanged()" id="page-size">
      <option value="10" selected="">10</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="500">500</option>
      <option value="1000">1000</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Scss:

```
.pagination-size{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-right: 32px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  float: left;

  select{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  }
}
```

i have angular 15 and i am using ag-grid-angular, here i need to bring in same line this pagesize div and also i need to bring one more div `stating please perform search` so page size should be at left, div with sentence to be at center and pagination controls at right end.
any help

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-ictp2y?file=app%2Fmy-grid-application%2Fmy-grid-application.component.html,app%2Fmy-grid-application%2Fmy-grid-application.component.ts,styles.css,app%2Fred-component%2Fred-component.component.ts)